# The name 'Permission' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Assets\Wikitude\Samples\Scripts\MenuController.cs(26,46): error CS0103: The name 'Permission' does not exist in the current context

```
#if UNITY_2018_3_OR_NEWER && UNITY_ANDROID

    if (!Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.Camera)) {
        Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.Camera);
    }
```

Comment: See documentation. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Android.Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission.html

Comment: Did you find a solution that worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

`Permission` is in the `UnityEngine.Android` namespace, so you need to include `using UnityEngine.Android` in the script if you want to refer to it simply as `Permission`:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Android;

...

#if UNITY_2018_3_OR_NEWER && UNITY_ANDROID

    if (!Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.Camera)) {
        Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.Camera);
    }
```